# How to generate a file given an original file and a diff file

Tags: diff, patch

I have a diff file based on the differences between two files:

```
git diff --no-index file1 file2
```

I would like to generate a `file3` (in a new directory) based on `file1` and the available diff using one `patch` command.

Technically, the `a/` and `b/` paths in the file don't match anymore and I have to reconstruct `file2` given `file1` and the diff.

Is there a single `patch` command to generate the new `file3`?

PS: I could write a script to generate first `file3` with the content of `file1` and then apply the patch.